# How do I use wildcards in an url request from browser

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, url, chromium, address-bar

I want to add 2 random uppercase letters to my url request from my chrome browser.

so in my ideal world I could do 
        youtube.com/?gl=[A-Z][A-Z] 
and it would go to 
        youtube.com/?gl=DI
 for example can I do this from the address bar somehow?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot.

This is not possible simply due to how url's work.

A url is a request to a server, which will then parse that url internally and present you with a page. If the url is not found, the server itself will still present a page, but the page transmits a status code 404 with a custom page saying: Page not found. Some browsers will understand the 404 error code and present you with a browser 404 page instead.

In the case of YouTube, they do not actually send you a 404 error code on their page not found page, but present you a page that says: video not found, or if you are not opening a video, they will still give you a youtube specific page possibly bringing you to your account settings. Only if your url is really impossible (for example, you add a non-existing page, youtube will transmit the 404 error code too.

In addition, a page can have multiple valid pages. How would your browser know what the one is that you want to visit? present them all? Present you the first one?

It would require you to open 26*26 = 676 concurrent connections to the server. Given that servers would easily get congested if this was allowed, so instead you usually are only allowed 2 simultanious connections at a given time, meaning that all other 674 connections have to wait for the first two to complete, this would mean that you would be waiting several minutes before the right page is presented, at least, if it were possible at all.

But there is no function to do so because this is simply not how the internet was designed. So you would need to write a script that would basically try every url, then analyze the website presented to see if it is what you are looking for and then give you the url, so you can enter the correct url the next time.